# Add Java in Python Flask Cloud Foundry

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I need to run java command from python flask application which is deployed using cf. How can we make java runtime available to this python flask app.

I tried using multi-buildpack, but java_buildpack expects some jar or war to be executed while deploying the application.

Any approach that would make java available to python flask app?

Answer (score 2):

The last buildpack in the buildpack chain is responsible for determining a command to start your application which is why the Java buildpack expects a JAR/WAR to execute.

The Java buildpack, as of writing this, does not ship a `supply` script so it can only be run as the *last* buildpack when using multi buildpack support.  It looks like that at some point in the future the Java buildpack will provide a `supply` script, but this is still being worked out [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/560).

---

For now, what you can do is use the [apt-buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack) and install a JRE/JDK that way.

To do this, add a file called `apt.yml` to the root of your project folder.  In that file, put the following:

```
---
packages:
- openjdk-8-jre
repos:
- deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
keys:
- https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0xEB9B1D8886F44E2A
```

This will tell the apt buildpack to add a PPA for Ubuntu Trusty where we can get the latest openjdk8.  This gets installed under `/home/vcap/deps/0`, which puts the `java` executable at `/home/vcap/deps/0/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`.

**Note:** The `java` binary is unfortunately not on the path because of the way Ubuntu uses `update-alternatives` and we can't use that tool to put it on the path in the CF app container because we don't have root access.

After setting that up, you'd follow the [normal instructions](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/use-multiple-buildpacks.html#cfcli) for using multiple buildpacks.

```
$ cf push YOUR-APP --no-start -b binary_buildpack
$ cf v3-push YOUR-APP -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack#v0.1.1 -b python_buildpack
```

**Note:** The process to push using multiple buildpacks will likely change in the future and `v3-push`, which is currently experimental, will go away.

**Note:** The example above hard codes version `v0.1.1` of the apt buildpack.  You should use the latest stable release, which you can find [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack/releases).  Using the master branch is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve your goal to combine Java and Python would be with [context-based routing](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/01/context-path-routes-hour-bluemix-cloud-foundry-apps/). I have an [example to combines Python and Node.js](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/Bluemix-ContextPathRouting), but the approach is the same.

Basically, you have a second app serving one or more paths of a domain / URI.